# For XDP programming,is there a good implementation for extracting the content of payload from TCP message

Tags: ebpf, xdp-bpf

For XDP programming,is there a good implementation for extracting the content of payload from TCP message.I want to get the transmission data content in the HTTP message,to do some analysis.I want to know how to get this part of the content and whether there is a good code that has been implemented.Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to send the full TCP payload to userspace, for arbitrary TCP packets?

Comment: Yes, almost that

Comment: What do you mean by "almost"?

Comment: I want to filter according to the content of the payload. To determine whether to drop